# How to return generic type from the following kotlin function?

Tags: kotlin, generics, methods

```kotlin
fun <T> create (myClass: Class<T>): T {
    return (T) //Error: Type parameter 'T' is not an expression
}
```

I tried return `<T>` . Still it is not working.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new instance using the parameter `myClass`, `T` is just a generic type not an `instance`

```
fun <T> create(myClass: Class<T>): T {
    return myClass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
}
```

Comment: I tried that already, but newInstance() is depricated.

Comment: updated the code with new usage!